# Rails - validates_each to allow only certain Emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for my rails3, devise, users model (name, email, etc...) I want to prevent bad domains from registering on the site.

The idea being I have a list of blacklisted domains (badplace.com, hotmail.com) ... and when a new user record goes to be saved, I check the email, if it has a domain with a bad domain, I add an error.

So what's the right way to implement this smartly in Rails...

Here's what I've been playing with:

In the User's Model

```
protected
  validates_each :email, :on => :create do |record, attr, value|
     domain = email.split("@").last
     record.errors.add attr, "That's a BAD EMAIL." unless value && !value.contains(domain)
  end
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this more easily with a `validates_format_of` and a regular expression:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :email, :without => /badplace\.com|hotmail\.com/, :message => "That's a BAD EMAIL."
end
```

EDIT:

For many addresses, you can do something like this:

```
INVALID_EMAILS = %w(badplace.com hotmail.com)
validates_format_of :email, :without => /#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/, :message => "That's a BAD EMAIL."
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Issue here is that I'll have dozens of bad emails. can without be a var? Also, what does message do? Don't I want to add a record.errors so the form can display what went wrong, note sure if message does that automatically? thxs

Comment: Yes, message is automatically added to `record.errors`. If you don't specify it, the default message for `validates_format_of` is "is invalid." Also, I'll update my answer in a second for how you can deal with many addresses.

Comment: hmm not luck so far. is part of your 2nd code above supposed to be a REGEX to determine what the domain is?

Comment: Also what's a, is that supposed to be the domain I extract form the value?

Comment: It works for me. Can you update your question with your `User` model? `a` is simply the block argument. I take the array of email addresses, use `.map` to escape any special characters in the address (such as the period), then join the array with `|`. In the end, the second regular expression looks exactly like the first one.

Comment: All I added to the user.rb file was:      INVALID_EMAILS = %w(gmail.com googlemail.com yahoo.com ymail.com rocketmail.com hotmail.com facebook.com)
  validates_format_of :email, :without => /#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/, :message => "That email domain won't do.", :on => :create

Comment: thanks for your help. What I don't understand yet is why you need the join with the |? not sure what that is doing. also I don't see where the actual regex is that determines what the domain of the email value in the create record is. Thanks for walking me through this one.

Comment: The code as you pasted works for me in a model, so there must be some other issue. What exactly is not working? Because I'm validating the email address against a regular expression, I need `|` to tell Ruby that I want to match *one* of the emails. `/foo|bar/` as a regular expression will match either `'foo'` or `'bar'`, but not `'baz'` or `'foobar'`. Google regular expressions to read more about them and how they work.

Comment: Interesting. well what's not working is, I can create a new user with what is an invalid email record like (thur351@gmail.com), it all works fine, when this new validates_format_of should have thrown an error and prevent the user record from being saved.

Comment: Could there be other validations that are interfering with the `validates_format_of`? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Good question. I am using Devise and Devise Invitable(https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable). I'm using the devise invitable method to create the user when I do this testing. is it possible that devise invitable skips validations somehow?

Comment: I just tried the same code with Devise and Devise invitable. Works fine for me. Are you sure you haven't added any other custom validations on the model? Can you post the model in its entirety?

Comment: Did you create the user record using devise invitable: like so, this is how I'm creating it: "class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController    def create  self.resource = resource_class.invite!(params[resource_name].merge(:invited_by => current_user.id))"

Comment: Here's the full Model, (thanks again I owe you a beer): http://pastebin.com/PWtKaadK

Comment: Line 162: `save(:validate => false)`. I'm guessing that's the problem. :)

Comment: Ahhhh jezz. So it's a devise invitable issue. Thanks vonconrad, that helps a ton. Off to the devise invitable forums :0

Comment: To get this to work with devise I'd have to do some serious devise/devise invitable hacking which would make upgrading dangerous. So I'm thinking about just adding a validation check in the invitations controller, but I'd like to DRY your validates_format_of so I can reuse the same INVALID_EMAILS, and not have duplicate code. Is there a way to wrap the validates_format_of into a method, so I can use it in the user.rb model and in any controller or model like devise_invitable?

Comment: You likely cannot wrap the validation, but you can wrap the array and regular expression, alleviating some of the pain.